# TypeError: fit() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y' with LDA algorithm

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I get this error when writing this code "TypeError: fit() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'":

```
# LDA
from sklearn.discriminant_analysis import LinearDiscriminantAnalysis


lda = LinearDiscriminantAnalysis(n_components = 20)
 
data_set_scaled= lda.fit_transform(data_set_scaled)
```

I tried to do this but to no avail:

```
from sklearn.discriminant_analysis import LinearDiscriminantAnalysis

LDA=LinearDiscriminantAnalysis()
lda = LDA(n_components = 20)
 
data_set_scaled= lda.fit_transform(data_set_scaled)
```

OR:

```
from sklearn.discriminant_analysis import LinearDiscriminantAnalysis as LDA

LDA=LinearDiscriminantAnalysis()
lda = LDA(n_components = 20)
 
data_set_scaled= lda.fit_transform(data_set_scaled)
```

Comment: Please provide the full stacktrace, so we know which line is throwing this.

Answer (score 1):

In order to fit a model, you need to use the training data (X, y):
X: Features
 y: target values, in your case you are trying to fit the module without the y values.

**Note:

X: array-like of shape (n_samples, n_features) 

Input samples.

y: array-like of shape (n_samples,) or (n_samples, n_outputs), default=None

Target values (None for unsupervised transformations).**

for more information check the docs:
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.discriminant_analysis.LinearDiscriminantAnalysis.html#sklearn.discriminant_analysis.LinearDiscriminantAnalysis.fit_transform

Answer (score 0):

You should specify the x and y
x is used for features
y is used for what ever you wanna predict with it

From your writing we can't guess your data so if you can share your data's columns maybe we can write a proper answer as well.